# How to create a nested codeblock style css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm needing to create CSS classes that can display content similar to this design image here: [design concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsVz8.png)

Obviously, the code statements themselves don't matter. But how can I create CSS that could wrap the containing content as seen in the image and have that work to n nested containers? I've been playing around with div tags and display: inline-block styling but nothing is working out.

Here is what I currently have, using flex-box. This is almost what I need except that the "rows" aren't setting their width to fit the text content as it just sets the width of everything to the largest width child... seems that this approach might not be possible.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.containerRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.dropContainer {
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc!important;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.purple {
  background-color: #872A61;
  color: white;
}

.green {
  background-color: #478B26;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container purple">
  <div class="containerRow">
    if (something == true) then
  </div>

  <div class="container green">
    <div class="containerRow">
      <div><b>where</b> something(x: Number, y:Number) <b>is</b></div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropContainer">
      Some more stuff again
    </div>

    <div class="dropContainer">
      Some more stuff again
    </div>

    <div class="containerRow">
      <b>end</b>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="containerRow">
    <b>end</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, stackoverflow lives up to its reputation. Gotta love getting downvoted for asking a question. I didn't ask for you to write code for me, I asked a css question and for guidance.

Comment: I didn't downvote but you should really read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Show what you have tried so far. Put some efford into your questions and you will recieve upvotes at some point.

Comment: I updated my question with what I've tried so far. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Use margins or padding styles with percentages to achieve the nth term.

Comment: Thanks for the few tips. I didn't ask for you to write code for me.